# Bitbake QA requires deletion of {bindir}

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I have a relatively simple receipt file (stripped version of the [ntp](http://cgit.openembedded.org/meta-openembedded/tree/meta-networking/recipes-support/ntp?h=morty)) with no installation of the `{bindir}`. However, unless I explicitly remove the `{bindir}` in the `do_install_append` I get a QA error saying:

```
ERROR: ntp-4.2.8p9-r0 do_package: QA Issue: ntp: Files/directories were installed but not shipped in any package:
/usr/bin
Please set FILES such that these items are packaged. Alternatively if they are unneeded, avoid installing them or delete them within do_install.
```

ntp: 1 installed and not shipped files. [installed-vs-shipped]
    ERROR: ntp-4.2.8p9-r0 do_package: Fatal QA errors found, failing task.

Why is the removal needed in this recipe? Is there some other recipe that is installing `{bindir}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some default do_install provided by https://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/poky/tree/meta/classes/base.bbclass. If you only want to install what you want. Please overwrite do_install () instead of do_install_append (). Otherwise you need to add all files FILES_${PN}.